# How to show a message on rosstage?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a Robot Simulation. I want to show a message about my robot status on the stage while this robot is running. For example, when my robot crash, I want a message pop up next to that robot saying that "The robot is crashed". Can any one help me please? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73894/how-to-show-a-message-on-rosstage?/) by [vv](https://answers.ros.org/users/6049/vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/65686/detect-collision-stage/#66224).

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0